# Can we skip or remove grammar check with JlanguageTool?

Tags: java, languagetool

Lets take an example

sentence :

> i am good.how are you?

Correction :

> ***I*** am good. ***How*** are you?

Expected :

> i am good.how are you? (Do not want any suggestion if there is no spelling mistake. )

Please let me know is there any step or trick so that we can skip this?

Comment: have you checked the documentation of that tool?

Comment: yes. But not found this one

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got the answer. By using selectRules() we can enable or disable any rules.

```
JLanguageTool jLanguageTool = new JLanguageTool(new AmericanEnglish());    
Set<CategoryId> categorySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
categorySet.add(new CategoryId("CASING"));
categorySet.add(new CategoryId("TYPOGRAPHY"));
Tools.selectRules(jLanguageTool, categorySet, Collections.emptySet(), Collections.emptySet(), Collections.emptySet(), false, false);
```